# does any one has VTI( vertical transverse isotropic) material properties input example?

Tags: abaqus

I try to understand how to input material properties using engineering constants for VTI material ( vertical transverse isotropic) with direction 3 being vertical direction. Does anyone has inp example showing how to input these material properties? For example, I don't know how to input nu12, n13? Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n8HM.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Do you ask for actual values or how these values are entered in the `*.inp` file? If the latter, you can always generate input from CAE and look inside.

Comment: I was asking if anyone has an example of the actual values look like? Thanks Roman

Answer (score 1):

As for transversely isotropic materials you have to provide 5 different parameters (I don't know what the vertical means, I never read this before).

For the convention on the poissons number please see Abaqus online documentation - conventions.

For your example. You should usually have one "master" direction (englisch is not my first language). And you have a plane perpendicular to this which has rotational symmetry. If your 3-direction is this (maybe the direction in which fibers are oriented) then your E11 and E22 values should be identical. Furthermore two of your possion numbers in your case 31 and 32 (prependicular/parallel sometimes called). Also the same directions of shear modules have to be identical.
The last shear modulus can be obtain via
G = E/2(1+nu) where E must be prependicular E modulus (2,1) and the poisson number must be the prependicular one (21)

Your constants: E33, E22=E11, nu31=nu32, nu12, G31=G32 , calculate G21 from above equation

For clarification[image: stiffness matrix]

from H. Schürmann - Konstruieren mit Faser-Kunststoff-Verbunden (construction with fiber reinforced materials)

NOTE: In this picture the 1 direction is the parallel direction where fibers are oriented, adjust it accordingly or follow what i wrote above.

Comment: Thank you so much Nic for this detailed explanation. I enjoyed it and appreciate it. Do you have any example values? Thanks

Comment: I am glad to hear that. What do you mean by example values? Values of a real transversly isotropic material?

Comment: I do have some from short-fiber reinforced plastics but they are from state of the art research so I don't want to put them public. May I ask what you would need them for? I would have contacted you but couldn't find your linkedin or something in your profile. Via PN I think it would be OK, only can't "spread" that data as you might be able to understand.